# how to check if database is really updated?

Tags: php

jquery-ajax sends post request to update database.

target.php:

```
$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
extract($_POST);

try {
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE members SET logged = :logged WHERE user = :user') ;
$stmt->execute(array(
':logged' => 1,
':user' => $user,
));
echo ('WELCOME ' . $user . ' !');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This works in any case, but it shouldn't work if - for example - given user does not exist in database.

How can I get one echo if database is really updated, or at least, if user really exists, and another echo if it does not?

Comment: `if ($stmt->execute()) { 
   // it worked
} else {
   // it didn't
}`

Comment: @Hackerman That only detects errors. A query that doesn't match any rows is not an error.

Comment: That's why is just a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the user exists (SELECT * FROM members WHERE user = :user) before you make the update request.

If you want to do it without checking if the user exists, use $stmt->rowCount() after $stmt->execute(...) in order to really determine how many records has been changed. Also, the function [$stmt->execute(...) returns true on success and false on failure](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$stmt->rowCount()` to find out if any rows were updated. It will be `0` if no rows were found, otherwise it will be non-zero.

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo "User $user not logged";
}
```

However, this will also return `0` if rows were found but there was nothing to change, because the value of `logged` is already the new value you tried to assign.